# seems that/appears that/looks like

Tags: word-choice, idiomatic-language

Two of my sheep were found dead this morning, so it seems that/appears that/looks like there's a wolf in the area.

Would "seems that", "appears that", and "looks like" all be natural to use here?

Comment: @OldBrixtonian I don't understand at all why you say a full stop is needed after "morning".  Continuing the sentence with "so" seems perfectly natural to this US English speaker.

Comment: @stangdon: Thanks. +1. Interesting point! I didn't stop to think **why** I would punctuate it like that. I'll re-write it as an answer, taking your comment into account. Do tell me if you still disagree with it.

Answer (score 1):

Two of my sheep were found dead this morning...

> so **it seems there's** a wolf...
>  or
>  so **there appears to
> be** a wolf...
>  or
>  so **it looks like there's** a wolf...

...in the area.

Any of those are good.

so **it appears there's** a wolf... is perhaps **slightly** less idiomatic.

so **it seems that there's...**
 and
 so **it appears that there's...**

are not grammatically wrong, but they are less concise and, to my big ears, less idiomatic.

By the way, if an initial statement is dramatic or shocking, a full stop is often used to let it sink in:

"I've shot my husband dead. So I'll probably miss today's gong-bath."

Answer (score 0):

> Two of my sheep were found dead this morning, so it seems that/appears that/looks like there's a wolf in the area.

All 3 choices are fine.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/seem

> seem
> verb [ I + adv/prep, L ]

> [ + (that) ] It seems (that) she can't come.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/appear

> appear
> verb

> appear verb (SEEM)

> B1 [ L or I, not continuous ]

> [ +(that) ] It appears (that) she left the party alone.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/look

> look
> verb
> look verb (SEEM)

> [It looks like (= It is likely that) we’ll be finished by January.